# End processing a stream using event-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a large JSON file using JSONStream and I want to call a method when the whole stream is processed.

```
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream'), es = require('event-stream');

es.pipeline(
  fs.createReadStream('file.json'),
  JSONStream.parse(['features', true]),
  es.map(function (data) {
    console.log("Added data");
  })
);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted. Save the read stream in a variable and pipe an on('end', function) on that read stream.

Answer (score 4):

I used 'event-stream' for processing of ~200kB files contain JSONs inside and got the issue when 'end' Event was never called when using 'event-stream', if I put .on('end') after event-stream pipes. But when I put it Before pipes - everything works just ok!

```
stream.on('end',function () {
            console.log("This is the End, my friend");                
     }).on('error',function (err) {
                console.error(err);
     }).pipe(es.split())
       .pipe(es.map(function (line, cb) {
                //Do anything you want here with JSON of line
                return cb();
            }));
```

[nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs),  [event-stream](/questions/tagged/event-stream)